# Is it possible: Phonegap and timer overlay when using other apps

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to evaluate if I can use Phonegap for a project, one of the main requirements is for a timer to be overlayed over the phones home screen, or any other application. The user should be able to use the phone as normal and once the timer runs out the Phonegap app should open up again. Is this possible with Phonegap, or would it be better to develop a native Android app?

I have no experience with Phonegap or Android apps in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova (aka Phonegap) apps are built using HTML/CSS/JavaScript and are "viewed" through a native "browser window," only we hide the navigation bar, toolbar, etc., so it looks like a regular app and not a browser. To my knowledge, Cordova apps cannot be used to create widgets, like what you are thinking of doing, because we need to use the native WebView code to display the web content.